# Collapse function in Bootstrap doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseHuiskamerdiner" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseHuiskamerdiner">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="width" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
         <div class="huiskamer-titel">
            <h1>Huiskamerdiner</h1>
            <img src="/images/huiskamerdiner.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
```

When I use this the datacollapse doesn't work, can someone help me with this?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle link

Comment: You can check it at suuzcompany.creabea.com

Comment: But we can't modify your site and can a fiddle - hence why everyone uses them, a link to your site is useless

Comment: Yes, but I can't put a whole site in fiddle Darren...

Comment: @Tonny-BoyVerweij, [this is why Darren was asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We need a minimal, complete and verifiable example otherwise we could spend a lot of time trying to fix a "datacollapse doesn't work" issue where it could be two dozen other things that are the problem. The link is helpful but far from being as helpful as a testable, controllable and editable example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you included bootstrap's .js file anywhere in your code? I can't see it

another thing is that I don't see any `collapseHuiskamerdiner` ID in your html

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseHuiskamerdiner" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseHuiskamerdiner">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="width" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
         <div class="huiskamer-titel">
            <h1>Huiskamerdiner</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</a>
<div id="collapseHuiskamerdiner">
    abc
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/svbge7zf/1/ - it appears to work

Comment: Yes it minifies in PHP so its included., but it still doesn't collapse, check suuzcompany.creabea.com

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that one of your further javascripts onload breaks and it causes that .collapse() plugin doesn't get applied on your elements - try commenting out anything except bootstrap related stuff and see what happens